# why c program with pointers does not work?

Tags: c, pointers

i am learning pointers in c.
and i wrote this code below but it did not run.
what is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    const int ARR_SIZE=5;
    int *arr;
    for(int i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++){
        *(arr+i) = i*10;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d. Element is: %d\n",i+1,*(arr+i));
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr` is an uninitialised pointer; you need to allocate some memory using `malloc`.

Comment: You should learn to ask better questions. What didn't work? Did it compile? Did it crash? What was the output? What is your guess as to why it's not working?

Comment: Is this Q only being close voted because *"Oh, hell I don't like the question"*?? Well, that is not valid enough reason to close vote a Q. There is a simplistic use compilable code example provided in the Q.So doesn't really call for a closure.

Comment: @AlokSave I agree, but it could be closed as exact duplicate to countless other posts. And there is really no point of re-opening it just to close it for another reason.

Comment: @Lundin: So let it be closed as a duplicate, how does closing a valid Q as too localized help the OP? and what kind of precinct do we set here? Reopening the q and closing it as duplicate might seem pointless to you and lot of others but it is the right thing to do. The idea of an programming forum is to get help to people who need it and should not depend on *convenience* or *likeness* of people providing that help.

Answer (score 6):

```
int *arr;
```

Is just an pointer, it's job is to point to another address. It should point to valid and sufficient memory so that you can write something at that memory.
Either,

- Allocate an array on local storage and point the pointer to that array or
- Allocate dynamic memory on heap and point the pointer to that memory.

---

**Solution 1:**

```
int array[ARR_SIZE];
int *arr = &array;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE);
//...
//...
//Free the memory once done with usage
free(arr);
```

---

Note In solution 2, when you allocate memory using `malloc` you have to explicitly deallocate the memory by calling `free` on the address returned by `malloc`.
In solution 1, You do not have to deallocate anything explicitly because `array` is a local/automatic array, it automatically gets deallocated when the scope`{`,`}` in which it is declared ends.

Answer (score 5):

You should initialize arr:

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE);
//... program
free(arr);
```

Comment: +1 but would also be worth mentioning that you now need to `free(arr)` later in the program